# Swagger with SpringMVC and CXF both at one time configuration

Tags: java, cxf, swagger

How I get swagger `api-docs` to generate data for both `SpringMVC` and `Apache CXF` in one project?
Now swagger displays only endpoints for SpringMVC. I used

pom.xml

```
<!-- Swagger SpringMVC -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<beans:bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />
```

I see REST endpoints for all classes with `@RequestMethod` annotations.

How I achieve resources list to also display CXF endpoints?
I was trying with following code in my `cxf-servlet.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mydlarz.myapp.services" />

<!-- Swagger writers -->
<bean id="resourceWriter"
    class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider" />
<bean id="apiWriter"
    class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider" />
<!-- Swagger API listing resource -->
<bean id="swaggerResourceJSON"
    class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON" />

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

<!-- this scans the classes for resources -->
<bean id="swaggerConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
<property name="resourcePackage" value="com.mydlarz.myapp.services"/>
<property name="version" value="1.0.0"/>
<property name="basePath" value="http://localhost:8080/services"/>
<property name="title" value="Petstore sample app"/>
<property name="description" value="This is a app."/>
<property name="contact" value="apiteam@wordnik.com"/>
<property name="license" value="Apache 2.0 License"/>
<property name="licenseUrl" value="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"/>
<property name="scan" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean"
    init-method="create">
    <property name="address" value="/services/" />
    <property name="serviceBeans">
        <list>
            <ref bean="resultSEI" />
            <ref bean="trackSEI" />
            <ref bean="tournamentSEI" />

            <ref bean="swaggerResourceJSON" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            <ref bean="exceptionMapper" />

            <!-- required for writing swagger classes -->
            <ref bean="resourceWriter" />
            <ref bean="apiWriter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What do you use to expose your REST endpoints? CXF, Spring MVC or both?

Comment: For one package I use Spring MVC, for another I use CXF

Comment: Okay, you won't be able to generate a single documentation for both, since each requires a different library.

Comment: So how I generate different api-docs URI for CXF?

Comment: You'd need to use swagger-core for CXF, and map its servlet to a different path than /api-docs. Honestly, I'm not sure swagger-springmvc and swagger-core can co-exist in a single app, but you can try.

Comment: Thanks. Which other tool like Swagger would you recommend to create documentation for CXF instead?

Comment: Considering I'm part of the Swagger team, I can't recommend anything else. Your architecture is just very uncommon which is why we currently don't offer support for it (two frameworks in a single project). Future versions may offer better support for it.